# Basic instructions for loading OS Terrain 50 data

Tags: qgis, data, terrain

Are there any basic instructions for using the OS Terrain data available online?

I do not have an issue extracting - it is all sat in a folder ready to go.

What I cannot work out how to do is to load the data in QGIS and then to change the settings so that I can use it to do a viewshed analysis.

Please note that I don't know how to use scripts or anything complicated! I'm using Wein on a Windows PC and have downloaded the data from OS as shapefiles and GML.

Answer (score 2):

When you say it is all in the folder ready to go, I suspect you have been fooled by OS helpfully compressing and recompressing and recompressing the data for you. I have a file called `terr50_gagg_gb.zip` which contains `data` and `doc` folders. On unpacking it inside `data` I have a series of folders `hp` to `tv` for the OS grids covered. In each of these are 6 and 100 zip files which have actual data in them.

So if you have already unpacked the data zip files you need then next step is to build a virtual raster of them using the `Raster->Miscellaneous->Build Virtual Raster` menu. Select the `.asc` files and choose a suitable output name for it.

You can either do this for just the area you are interested in or for the whole country (if you have space).

```
 gdalbuildvrt -a_srs epsg:27700 terrain.vrt *.asc
```

I then translated it into a GeoTif:

```
 gdal_translate -CO compress=deflate -CO tiled=yes terrain.vrt terrain.tif
```

and added some overviews:

```
  gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW DEFLATE terrain.tif 2 4 8 16 32
```

to end up with a 214Mb file.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. I did see that when downloaded you then have to upzip for each square. Atm I am just working with one set of data to make it easy, square NF. However, I don't have any tiff files I only have vector files (line and point) and gml files. Which may mean I have been silly and donwloaded the wrong data.

Comment: they should be .asc files - I've added a note on how to convert to tif for you

Comment: Thanks iant, I am now downloading and unzipping the right (asc) files and will have another go.

Comment: Ok, I think I have managed the first two steps. I have imported the asc files, and created a geotiff. I can now see the terrain for the area I am working with.

Comment: Now how to do the analysis......my colleague has asked for the following: We used the free 50 mm Digital Terrain Model (DTM) from the OS, gave the proposed development a height e.g. approximately 8 metres for a 2 storey house within the site boundary  and viewing height of approximately 2 metres. We would sometimes ‘screen’ the ZTV by introducing shape files for areas  of woodland and settlement.

Comment: I'm not really sure what tools to use to do this. the proposed development could be point or polygon depending on what type of shapefile is best.

Comment: You need to ask a new question for that